# Does Spring Roo build the html templates for the finders?

Tags: spring-roo

I am using Spring Roo 2 RC1 with Spring Tool Suite 3.8.3.  I built a project to list the contents of a MySQL table and to allow me to edit it.  Everything is working except for the finders.  They are not showing up on the web app.  Is this because I have to configure that part myself?  Below is my log.roo file.

```
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 [rev 28015e3] log opened at 2017-03-07 14:07:55
project setup --topLevelPackage org.oclc --projectName "sfdcIntegration" --java 8 --packaging JAR
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 [rev 28015e3] log closed at 2017-03-07 14:07:57
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 [rev 28015e3] log opened at 2017-03-07 14:08:00
jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database MYSQL
entity jpa --class ~.domain.SfdcAccount --table sfdc_account --identifierColumn account_id --identifierStrategy AUTO --sequenceName sequenceName --identifierType java.lang.Integer
field string --fieldName sfdcRecordId --column sfdc_record_id --sizeMax 18
field string --fieldName siebelRowId --column siebel_row_id --sizeMax 18
field string --fieldName sfdcParentId --column sfdc_parent_id --sizeMax 18
field string --fieldName siebelParentId --column siebel_parent_id --sizeMax 15
field string --fieldName sfdcRecordTypeId --column sfdc_record_type_id --sizeMax 18
field string --fieldName siebelRecordTypeId --column siebel_record_type_id --sizeMax 30
field string --fieldName siebelResponsibleInstitutionName --column siebel_responsible_institution_name --sizeMax 15
field string --fieldName responsibleInstitutionSymbol --column responsible_institution_symbol --sizeMax 40
field string --fieldName billingStreet --column billing_street --sizeMax 255
// [failed] field string --fieldName billingStreet --column billing_street --sizeMax 255
field string --fieldName billingCity --column billing_city --sizeMax 40
field string --fieldName billingState --column billing_state --sizeMax 80
field string --fieldName billingPostalCode --column billing_postal_code --sizeMax 45
field string --fieldName billingCountry --column billing_country --sizeMax 80
field string --fieldName name --column name --sizeMax 255
// [failed] field string --fieldName name --column name --sizeMax 255
field string --fieldName fax --column fax --sizeMax 40
field string --fieldName shippingStreet --column shipping_street --sizeMax 255
field string --fieldName shippingCity --column shipping_city --sizeMax 40
field string --fieldName shippingState --column shipping_state --sizeMax 80
field string --fieldName shippingPostalCode --column shipping_postal_code --sizeMax 45
field string --fieldName shippingCountry --column shipping_country --sizeMax 80
field string --fieldName oclcAccountId --column oclc_account_id --sizeMax 50
field string --fieldName oclcRegistryId --column oclc_registry_id --sizeMax 15
field string --fieldName accountType --column account_type --sizeMax 40
field string --fieldName dataCenter --column data_center --sizeMax 15
field number --fieldName designatedVotingMember --type byte --column designated_voting_member 
exit
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 [rev 28015e3] log closed at 2017-03-07 14:28:15
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 [rev 28015e3] log opened at 2017-03-07 16:51:41
field number --fieldName disableMailing --type byte --class ~.domain.SfdcAccount --column disable_mailings
field number --fieldName oclcBoardOfTrustees --type byte --column oclc_board_of_trustees
field number --fieldName apCouncilExecutiveCommittee --type byte --column ap_council_executive_committee
field number --fieldName oclcGlobalCouncil --type byte --column oclc_global_council
field number --fieldName oclcArcExecutiveCommittee --type byte --column oclc_arc_executive_committee
field string --fieldName memberStatus --column member_status --sizeMax 30
field string --fieldName accountStatus --column account_status --sizeMax 30
field string --fieldName currencyIsoCode --column currency_iso_code --sizeMax 40
field string --fieldName accountSubType --column account_sub_type --sizeMax 15
field string --fieldName groupNumber --column group_number --sizeMax 22
field string --fieldName groupType --column group_type --sizeMax 50
field string --fieldName groupCode --column group_code --sizeMax 30
field string --fieldName primaryLibraryType --column primary_library_type --sizeMax 100
field string --fieldName secondaryLibraryType --column secondary_library_type --sizeMax 100
field string --fieldName salesRep --column sales_rep --sizeMax 255
field string --fieldName ownerName --column owner_name --sizeMax 255
field number --fieldName sfdcAccountStatus --type java.lang.Long --column sfdc_account_status
field number --fieldName sfdcLastUpdatedFlag --type byte --column sfdc_last_updated_flag
field date --fieldName sfdcLastUpdatedDate --type java.util.Calendar --column sfdc_last_updated_date --persistenceType JPA_TIMESTAMP --dateTimeFormatPattern SS
field number --fieldName siebelLastUpdatedFlag --type byte --column siebel_last_updated_flag
field date --fieldName siebelLastUpdatedDate --type java.util.Calendar --column siebel_last_updated_date --persistenceType JPA_TIMESTAMP --dateTimeFormatPattern MM
field string --fieldName lastUpdatedBy --column last_updated_by --sizeMax 45
field date --fieldName lastUpdatedDate --type java.util.Calendar --column last_updated_date --persistenceType JPA_TIMESTAMP --dateTimeFormatPattern MM
field string --fieldName sfdcResponsibleInstitutionName --column sfdc_responsible_institution_name --sizeMax 18
field number --fieldName newRecordFlag --type byte --column new_record_flag
field number --fieldName isDeleted --type byte --column isDeleted
field number --fieldName loadId --type java.lang.Integer --column load_id
field number --fieldName activeFlag --type byte --column active_flag
field number --fieldName sfdcSent --type byte --column sfdc_sent
field string --fieldName region --column region --sizeMax 45
field number --fieldName relation --type byte --column relation
field number --fieldName hasError --type byte --column has_error
field number --fieldName siebelSent --type byte --column siebel_sent
repository jpa --all
finder add --entity ~.domain.SfdcAccount --name findByOclcAccountId
finder add --entity ~.domain.SfdcAccount --name findBySfdcRecordId
finder add --entity ~.domain.SfdcAccount --name findBySiebelRowId
// [failed] finder add --entity ~.domain.SfdcAccount --name findByOclcSymbol
field string --fieldName oclcSymbol --column oclc_symbol --sizeMax  12 
hint
finder add --entity ~.domain.SfdcAccount --name findByOclcSymbol
service --all
web mvc setup
web mvc view setup --type THYMELEAF
web mvc templates setup --type THYMELEAF
web mvc controller --entity ~.domain.SfdcAccount --responseType THYMELEAF
web mvc finder --all --responseType THYMELEAF
exit
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 [rev 28015e3] log closed at 2017-03-07 18:37:44
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 [rev 28015e3] log opened at 2017-03-08 13:38:19
exit
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 [rev 28015e3] log closed at 2017-03-08 18:04:35
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 [rev 28015e3] log opened at 2017-03-09 09:35:01
// [failed] web mvc finder --entity ~.domain.SfdcAccount --package org.oclc.web --pathPrefix 'find' --queryMethod findBy --responseType THYMELEAF 
// [failed] web mvc finder --entity ~.domain.SfdcAccount --package org.oclc.web --pathPrefix 'find' --queryMethod findBySiebelRowId --responseType THYMELEAF 
web mvc finder --all --responseType THYMELEAF --pathPrefix 'find'
exit
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 [rev 28015e3] log closed at 2017-03-09 10:23:10
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 [rev 28015e3] log opened at 2017-03-09 12:06:44
finder add --entity ~.domain.SfdcAccount --name findByOclcSymbolEqualsIgnoreCase
hint
web mvc finder --all --responseType THYMELEAF
service --all
web mvc templates setup --type THYMELEAF 
web mvc finder --entity ~.domain.SfdcAccount --responseType THYMELEAF
// [failed] web mvc finder --entity ~.domain.SfdcAccount --queryMethod findByOclcSymbolEqualsIgnoreCase 
// [failed] web mvc finder --entity ~.domain.SfdcAccount --queryMethod findByOclcAccountId findByOclcSymbolEqualsIgnoreCase 
// [failed] web mvc finder --entity ~.domain.SfdcAccount --queryMethod findByOclcAccountId
// [failed] web mvc finder --entity ~.domain.SfdcAccount --queryMethod findByOclcAccountId, findBySfdcRecordId, findBySiebelRowId, findByOclcSymbol, findByOclcSymbolEqualsIgnoreCase 
// [failed] web mvc finder --entity ~.domain.SfdcAccount --queryMethod SfdcAccount.class
// [failed] web mvc finder --entity ~.domain.SfdcAccount --queryMethod SfdcAccount
// [failed] web mvc finder --entity ~.domain.SfdcAccount --queryMethod findBy
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 [rev 28015e3] log closed at 2017-03-09 18:39:52
```

I created a DTO form bean as follows:

```
dto --class ~.domain.SiebelRowIdFormBean 
field string --fieldName siebelRowId --sizeMax 18
finder add --entity ~.domain.SfdcAccount --name findBySiebelRowIdEquals --formBean ~.domain.SiebelRowIdFormBean
```

but when I try to publish it I must supply a pathPrefix.  I can't figure out what the pathPrefix is.  This is what I entered:

```
web mvc finder --entity ~.domain.SfdcAccount --responseType THYMELEAF --queryMethod findBySiebelRowIdEquals --package org.oclc.web --pathPrefix sfdcaccounts/search
```

but I get this error:

```
ERROR: Already exists a controller associated to entity 'SfdcAccount' in the same package 'org.oclc.web', with different 'pathPrefix'. Specify a different 'pathPrefix' and a different package that the existing one to create a new one, or the same 'package' and 'pathPrefix' to update the existing controller.
```

I think I figured out how to re-build the finders via the "web mvc finder" command.  I deleted the search entities under the web package.  Then I entered "web mvc finder --all --responseType THYMELEAF" again.  Spring Roo regenerated the finders for me.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 provides the necessary commands to create new finders in the Spring Data Repositories. After that creation, it provides the necessary commands to publish them into the web layer.

But **not every finders are available** to be published into the web layer.

As I could see in your `log.roo`, all your finders use the default Spring Data nomenclature `findBy` without specify a projection as defaultReturnType or DTO as formBean. As you could check, they're only been generated in the interferface `~.repository.SfdcAccountRepository` because they doesn't use the QueryDSL implementation.

The finder methods that could be published into the web layer needs some specific parameters to work correctly with DataTables component. So, only the finders generated like the following will be able to be published.

```
finder add --entity ~.domain.ENTITY --name findByFIELD --formBean ~.domain.DTO
```

Try to use a DTO as formBean of some of your finders above and after that, publish the finder using the `web mvc finder` command.

You'll see that this works correctly!

Maybe this is not really clear at the Spring Roo reference guide, so I've just created the following task to review it.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3903

Thanks for you contribution to the Spring Roo project!

Hope it helps!

Comment: I added a DTO, but I still cant' get the web mvc finder command to work.  I added more information to the initial question.